# Regex to find attribute in xml tag and replace its value (node/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a Cordova config.xml file and I'm writing a script to bump up the version. A sample of the file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget android-packageName="com.demo.android" id="com.demo.ios" ios-CFBundleIdentifier="com.demo.ios.dev" version="1.16.6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name short="DEMO DEV">DEMO</name>
```

I want to replace the value of the attribute `version` that is inside the `<widget>` tag, but without affecting at all any other attribute, including the one in the `<?xml` tag.

So, simply put, find and replace the value of the attribute `version` inside the `widget` tag.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Use this regex to look for the version number ```(?<=\<widget.*(?<=version\=\"))(\d+\.?)+``` and then replace the string with suitable replacement.

Comment: Javascript does not have look behind.

Comment: Is there only one `widget` tag. If not, can it possibly _not_ have a version ? Because the whole `<widget.*?version=` thing just won't cut it. That's why I posted a hairy regex, to avoid such trivia, and is the only way it can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following regex and test it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/e7oNcP/2):

```
/(<widget [\S\s]*?version=")[^"]+("[\S\s]*?>)/gmi
```

In short, what am I doing:

1. Group everything from `<widget` to `version="`
2. Select everything except a `"`
3. Group everything until the next `>`.

You can then replace it with `$1(new version)$2`.

Here is a simple demo:

```js
const versionRegex = /(<widget [\S\s]*?version=")[^"]+("[\S\s]*?>)/gmi;

const content = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget android-packageName="com.demo.android" id="com.demo.ios" ios-CFBundleIdentifier="com.demo.ios.dev" version="1.16.6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name short="DEMO DEV">DEMO</name>`

const newVersion = 'testVersion';
const replaced = content.replace( versionRegex, `$1${ newVersion }$2` )
document.getElementById( 'result' ).innerText = replaced;
```

```css
pre {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Doesn't span lines: https://regex101.com/r/e7oNcP/3. Even if you fix that, doesn't parse the widget tag correctly: https://regex101.com/r/e7oNcP/4

Answer (score 2):

This do what you want:

```
let xml; // Your xml file
const version = "0.8.5"
xml = xml.replace(/(<widget.+version=")([0-9\.]+)(".*>)/, "$1"+version+"$3")
```

Explanation of regex matches:

- First match of the regex (`$1`): first string which begin with `<widget` with all chars until `version="`
- The second match (`$2`, not in the replace cause this is the string we want to replace) is the version number
- The last match is all chars until caret closing `>` of the widget attribute.
- And the global match is this three matches together

Answer (score 0):

Try

Find `/<widget(?=\s)(?=((?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\sversion\s*=\s*)(?:(['"])([\S\s]*?)\2)((?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)*?>))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>/`

Replace `<widget$1$2NEW_VERSION$2$4`

https://regex101.com/r/1KnW0M/1

*(The old version is in Capture Group 3 incase it's needed.)*

More info

```
 # Begin Widget tag

 < widget                 
 (?= \s )
 (?=                           # Asserttion (a pseudo atomic group)
      (                             # (1 start), Up to Version attribute
           (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
           \s version \s* = \s* 
      )                             # (1 end)
      (?:
           ( ['"] )                      # (2), Quote
           ( [\S\s]*? )                  # (3), Version Value
           \2 
      )
      (                             # (4 start), After Version attribute
           (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )*?
           >
      )                             # (4 end)
 )

 # Have the version, just match the rest of tag

 \s+ 
 (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )+

 >                             # End Widget tag
```